# Copy/duplicate files in MongoDB, GridFS, and NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs

I use MongoDB and GridFS in NodeJS to store files. Because of a requirement (files are in 1 to 1 correspondence with other data) I need to copy/duplicate files on the server side upon a request from the client side (AngularJS). I don't just want to copy/duplicate the corresponding data in fs.files but also in fs.chunks and simultaneously update the file's metadata. How would I do this? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

We have the same requirement - copy files on server. 
The only way we could find was to basically download and re-upload:

```
bucket.openDownloadStreamByName(name)
    .pipe(buckent.openUploadStream(new_name))
```

Answer (score 0):

One Way to go is the following one

1. Create a dump of the required collection.
2. Create a unique index with the `dropDups:true` option

   db.collection('stuffs').ensureIndex({identifier: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})

   dropDups will remove all the duplicate documents.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Apologies but it seems my question was not clearly put. What I would need is the following: upon a request from the client side (angular), the complete file should be copied/duplicated (with new metadata obtained from the client side). BTW, I am using gridfs-stream and formidable. Thanks again. PS: I just clarified that in my question.

Comment: So you want to update the documents or insert them without touching the existing ones even if is the same ?

Comment: Indeed, I want to create a copy/duplicate of the file in the database, and only change metadata. However, I don't want to create just a copy/duplicate in fs.files pointing to the original chunks but I also need to duplicate the chunks since the files are in one-to-one correspondence with other data, and upon deleting that other data, the corresponding file also need to be deleted, hence, the need for duplicating the file chunks as well. Thanks again!